# Is there a way to populate an input field from a list of buttons in React?

Tags: reactjs, button, input

I am building a React application and I need to populate an input field from a list of predefined buttons (the text of the btn should be displayed on the input if the user clicks on the btn).
For example: let's suppose the user sees 3 btns with the following text for each: 'Banana', 'Apple','Orange'.
If the user clicks on the Banana btn, the world 'Banana' must appear on the input field.
Here is the code of App.js :

```
function App() {
  const [suggestiveListBorder, setSuggestiveListBorder] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <ListOfExercises
        suggestiveListBorder={suggestiveListBorder}
      ></ListOfExercises>

      <div className="pages">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route
            path="/chest"
            element={
              <ChestWorkouts
                setSuggestiveListBorder={setSuggestiveListBorder}
              />
            }
          />
          <Route path="/hamstrings" element={<HamstringsWorkouts />} />
```

the code of ListOfExercises.js

```
export function ListOfExercises({ suggestiveListBorder }) {
  const currentLocation = useLocation();
  let currentLocat = currentLocation.pathname;
  const chestExos = exercisesData.exercises.chest_Exercises;

  return (
    <>
      {currentLocat === "/chest" ? (
        <ChestExosList
          suggestiveListBorder={suggestiveListBorder}
          chestExos={chestExos}
        />
      ) : currentLocat === "/hamstrings" ? (
        <span>hamstrings</span>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}
```

the code of ChestExosList.js

```
export function ChestExosList({ chestExos, suggestiveListBorder }) {
  const chestValues = Object.values(chestExos);

  return (
    <div
      className="chest-exos-list-container"
      style={{
        border: suggestiveListBorder,
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <p className="chest-exos-paragraph">
          Have no idea about the exercise you want to do ? Here are some
          suggestions :
        </p>
      </div>
      <Stack direction={"row"} spacing={2} sx={{ marginBottom: "30px" }}>
        {chestValues.map(
          (elem, index) =>
            index < 8 &&
            index >= 0 && (
              <Button type="secondary" key={index}>
                {elem}
              </Button>
            )
        )}
      </Stack>
```

the code of Chest page

```
const Chest = ({ setSuggestiveListBorder }) => {
  const { workouts, dispatch } = useWorkoutsContext();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWorkouts = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("/api/workouts");
      const json = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        dispatch({ type: "SET_WORKOUTS", payload: json });
      }
    };

    fetchWorkouts();
  }, [dispatch]);

  const antIcon = (
    <LoadingOutlined
      style={{
        fontSize: 50,
      }}
    />
  );

  return (
    <div className="chest-page-container">
      <div className="chest-page-workouts">
        {!workouts && <Spin spinning={true} indicator={antIcon}></Spin>}
        {workouts &&
          workouts.map((workout) => (
            <WorkoutDetails workout={workout} key={workout._id} />
          ))}
      </div>
      <WorkoutForm setSuggestiveListBorder={setSuggestiveListBorder} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

and a snippet of the code of WorkoutForm.js :

```
return (
    <form className="chest-workouts-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="chest-workouts-form-inner">
        <h3>Add a New Workout</h3>

        <label>Excercise Title : </label>

          <input
            onMouseOver={() => {
              setSuggestiveListBorder("1.5px solid #1aac83");
            }}
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
            value={title}
            // value=""
            className={emptyFields.includes("title") ? "form-msg-error" : ""}
          />
        ...
```

thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You can add a different `onClick` event on each button (see first button in example) or a more generic one if you're planning on having many buttons (second button in example)

```
const Component = () => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
    const firstButtonText = "First button";

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => setInputValue(firstButtonText)}>{firstButtonText}</button
            <button onClick={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.innerHTML)}>Second button</button>
            <input value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)} />
    </>
    )

}
```

Comment: thank you, solved the problem but I got into another problem: now I can not get the data displayed on the UI once I click on ''Add workout'' , meaning when I submit the form. the input that receives the text of the btn is considered empty by react as far as I understand. Here you can see a demo of the prblm : https://streamable.com/fl4ifa
`
const handleFormInputChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    setTitle(inputValue);
  };  <input    onChange={(e) => handleFormInputChange(e)}
            value={inputValue ? inputValue : title ? title : ""}
          />
`

Comment: please give me an answer

Comment: Not a 100% sure, but it might be related to your input having 2 states. I'm not sure why there is the `inputValue` and the `title` state. You should only have one state which controls what the input value is. And call that same state setter in the input onChange and on button click

Comment: ok I will try this and let you know if it works

Answer (score 1):

Create state for you input value :

const [inputValue,setInputValue]=useState('');

Give this value to your input:

```
 <input
        onMouseOver={() => {
          setSuggestiveListBorder("1.5px solid #1aac83");
        }}
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        value={inputValue}
        className={emptyFields.includes("title") ? "form-msg-error" : ""}
      />
```

On your button click, you set this value:

```
<button onClick={()=> setInputValue("button one"}>...
```

Do the same for your other buttons

Comment: can you help me with a problem that I faced when I solved this 1st prblm ?